Correct price not reflected based on product variation when markeplace page loaded
I am stucked with this issue that correct price is not loaded based on product variation setup in drupal 9.5.
Here is my product variation.

And here is my marketplace product price and variation displayed

Please help me with this issue or any kind of hint so i can resolve it.
